# AJAX call when external page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax call that appends a div from an external webpage to a div on my local page. It works *but* when an external page has a loading page that shows only a spinner or loading bar of some sort first, then it doesn't work because my script isn't able to find the div I want yet.
example snippet from my code:

```
 loadExtPage('https://www.voltage.com/events/','h2.tribe-events-list-event-title.entry-title.summary, div.author.location','secEvents');

 function loadExtPage(url,extEl,intDiv) { 
            //source: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/
            //loading external content into specific div on page 
            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: true,
            aysnc: false,
            success: function(res) {

            //attempt to wait for external page to be done loading
            $(res.responseText).ready( function () {          
            var search = $(res.responseText).find(extEl).each(function(){
                  console.log("Loading to:" + intDiv);
                  $('#'+intDiv).append($(this).html());

             });
             if(!search.length) {
                $('#'+intDiv).append("<h4>Sorry couldn't load content.</h4>");
             }
           });
 });

    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="secEvents">
    <p>External page content goes here.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If anyone has an idea on how to wait for the external page to load first before the ajax call tries to fetch content, please let me know!
Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Sounds like your external page returns unreliable responses.  Good luck with that.  The only thing I can think of is to try loading it again, if it doesn't contain the div you're looking for.  Repeat until you give up.

Comment: why not use an iframe to display the content?

Comment: @biancamihai not using iframes because there was a cross domain issue so just appending to empty divs

Comment: @wwwmarty I think that's the best thing I can do for now, thanks for the advice I'll try to implement a way to reload the call for a set amount of time